# Caught TypeError while rendering: Decimal('51.8') is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, django

I am using Python 2.6.5 and Django 1.3 .while running the below code i am getting the above  error

```
if chart_list is not None:
    if isinstance(chart_list, (Chart, PivotChart)):
        chart_list = [chart_list]
    chart_list = [c.hcoptions for c in chart_list]
    render_to_list = [s.strip() for s in render_to.split(',')]
    for hco, render_to in izip_longest(chart_list, render_to_list):
        if render_to:
            hco['chart']['renderTo'] = render_to
    embed_script = (embed_script % (simplejson.dumps(chart_list,skipkeys=False,   ensure_ascii=True, 
  check_circular=True, allow_nan=True, cls=None),
                                    CHART_LOADER_URL))
else:
    embed_script = embed_script %((), CHART_LOADER_URL)
return mark_safe(embed_script
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use of custom JSONEncoder should help

```
class DecimalEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, decimal.Decimal):
            return float(o)
        super(DecimalEncoder, self).default(o)

# and then:
json.dumps(chart_list,..., cls=DecimalEncoder)
```

---

### Updated

Updated according with Daniel's comment (more DRY way)

```
from django.core.serializers.json import DjangoJSONEncoder
json.dumps(chart_list,..., cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
```

Comment: In fact, pretty much exactly that code is included in django as `django.core.serializers.json.DjangoJSONEncoder`.

Comment: Thank you Daniel, as usual your comments very useful. The answer has been updated according with your clarification.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman  Thanks you so much you both for answers i solved my problem

Comment: @AlexeySavanovich really appreciate you keeping the original "generic" answer as well, as I happened on this problem outside of Django.

Comment: Unfortunately, the updated version behaves quite differently from the original, as DjangoJSONEncoder returns strings for Decimals as opposed to floats

Answer (score -1):

An easy and quick solution is, Convert this decimal object to string before passing to `dumps` method

```
decimal_value = Decimal('51.8')
simplejson.dumps(str(decimal_value))
```

Comment: this is not needed any longer - simplejson accepts decimals as-is